# TI-Basic file manager

Tags: file, ti-basic

Tested on my TI-84 Plus CE.

Variables:

- `F`: Stores the file listing's ID
- `N`: Stores the current file's ID
- `I`, `J`, `L`: Temporary variables
- `Str1`: Used for input and output
- `Str2`, `Str3`: Temporary variables
- `Str0`: Used for storing the actual data
- `⌊DATA`: Stores the start of the files

The DATA- programs are for storing files by ID#, the FILES- programs are used for storing files by name.

DATAADD (creates a new file, returns the file's ID)

```
augment(⌊DATA,{⌊DATA(dim(⌊DATA))})→⌊DATA
dim(⌊DATA)-1→N
```

DATAGET (gets the contents of the current file)

```
If ⌊DATA(N+1)-⌊DATA(N)
Then
sub(Str0,⌊DATA(N)+1,⌊DATA(N+1)-⌊DATA(N))→Str1
Else
" "→Str1
End
Str1
```

DATAINI (initializes/resets the files)

```
" "→Str0
{1}→⌊DATA
```

DATASET (sets the contents of a file)

```
length(Str1)-⌊DATA(N+1)+⌊DATA(N)→L
If length(Str0)-⌊DATA(N+1)>0
Then
sub(Str0,1,⌊DATA(N))+Str1+sub(Str0,⌊DATA(N+1),length(Str0)-⌊DATA(N+1))→Str0
Else
sub(Str0,1,⌊DATA(N))+Str1→Str0
End
For(I,N+1,dim(⌊DATA))
⌊DATA(I)+L→⌊DATA(I)
End
```

DATATEST (test program for the DATA- programs)

```
prgmDATAINI
prgmDATAADD
prgmDATAGET
Disp Str1
"ABC"→Str1
prgmDATASET
prgmDATAGET
Disp Str1
prgmDATAADD
prgmDATAGET
Disp Str1
1→N
prgmDATAGET
Disp Str1
2→N
"DEF"→Str1
prgmDATASET
prgmDATAGET
Disp Str1
1→N
prgmDATAGET
Disp Str1
"12"→Str1
prgmDATASET
prgmDATAGET
Disp Str1
```

FILES (semi-GUI file manager interface)

```
Lbl L
Menu("Choose an action","List files",LI,"Create file",CR,"Open file",OP,"View file",VI,"Edit file",ED,"View home screen",VH,"Advanced features...",AD,"Exit",E)
Lbl AD
Menu("Advanced features","Initialize/reset files",RF,"Initialize/reset all data",RD,"View current file ID",ID,"Back",L)
Lbl LI
prgmFILESLST
Pause Str1
Goto L
Lbl CR
Input "FILENAME: ",Str1
prgmFILESADD
Goto L
Lbl OP
Input "FILENAME: ",Str1
prgmFILESID
Goto L
Lbl VI
prgmDATAGET
Pause Str1
Goto L
Lbl ED
Input "NEW CONTENTS: ",Str1
prgmDATASET
Goto L
Lbl VH
Pause ""
Goto L
Lbl RF
prgmFILESINI
Goto L
Lbl RD
prgmDATAINI
Goto L
Lbl ID
Disp N
Goto L
Lbl E
```

FILESADD (creates a new file)

```
Str1→Str2
prgmDATAADD
N→I
F→N
prgmDATAGET
Str1+" "+Str2+" "+toString(I)→Str1
prgmDATASET
```

FILESID (gets the file's ID)

```
Str1→Str2
F→N
prgmDATAGET
Str1→Str3
3→I
While I and Str1≠Str2
Str3→Str1
I→J
inString(Str1," ",I)+1→I
If I
Then
sub(Str1,J,I-J)→Str1
Else
sub(Str1,J,length(Str1)-J)→Str1
End
End
inString(Str3," ",I)+1→I
inString(Str3," ",I)→J
If J
Then
sub(Str3,I,J-I)→Str1
Else
sub(Str3,I,length(Str3)-I+1)→Str1
End
expr(Str1)→N
```

FILESINI (initializes the file index)

```
prgmDATAADD
N→F
```

FILESLST (lists the files' names, space separated)

```
F→N
prgmDATAGET
" "→Str2
2→I
While I
inString(Str1," ",I+1)→J
If not(J)
Goto E
Str2+sub(Str1,I,J-I)→Str2
inString(Str1," ",J+1)→I
End
Lbl E
If length(Str2)<3
Then
""→Str1
Else
sub(Str2,3,length(Str2)-2)→Str1
End
```

FILESTST (test program for the FILE- programs)

```
prgmFILESINI
prgmFILESLST
Disp Str1
"ABC"→Str1
prgmFILESADD
prgmFILESLST
Disp Str1
"123"→Str1
prgmFILESADD
prgmFILESLST
Disp Str1
```